# Loopback required the Node Cluster module, which is incompatible with Passenger

Tags: node.js, nginx, loopback

I am trying to deploy my `loopback service`. But I am encountering a problem where i am unable to access it.

When trying to access I get the following error message:

```
Trace: You required the Node Cluster module, which is incompatible with Passenger, a non-functional shim was returned and your app may still work. However, please remove the related code as soon as possible.
```

Now I am not 100% sure this is the reason why I am unable to access it but it is not throwing any other messages.

I've already looked into the problem however I haven't found a solution. It seems that loopback uses something called `shirtId` which is a node module that uses a cluster function.

Removing this node module will result in my application not being able to start.

Has anyone else had this problem and maybe know of a fix?

Comment: No solution so far. I guess you gotta change the host

Comment: Please correct the question its not `shirtId` it is `shortId`. It is used by `loopback-datasource-juggler` to generate shortId's like uuid etc. If you are not using that feature you can fork the `loopback-datasource-juggler` and remove the appropriate codes where `shortId` is used. After that you can publish your own npm module and use that in project.

Comment: struck with the same problem  , did you manage to find a solution for this ?